# iOS executing methods one after another serially

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperationqueue

I know this similar question has already been asked but my problem is even by using NSOperationQueue with

```
  NSOperationQueue *aQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
  [aQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
```

Then even Methods does not execute in the order i.e. FIFO.

MethodA (Takes 5 seconds) -> MethodB (Takes 2 seconds) -> MethodC (Takes 1 second).

If i put them into NSOperationQueue i.e.

```
 [aQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{


[self MethodA];

}];

 [aQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{


[self MethodB];

 }];


[aQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{

[self MethodC];

 }];
```

MethodC executes first then A then B

I want them to execute in order the entered. 
MethodA->MethodB->Methodc

Answer (score 1):

One option would indeed to use dependencies as Fonix said: MethodA depends on MethodB which depends on MethodC.

Just use the `dependencies` property (an array of `NSOperations`) in `NSOperation` or the method `addDependency:`.

However, since you're already using blocks, why not use `GCD`:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self methodA];
    [self methodB];
    [self methodC];
});
```

Comment: Ok i have added dependancies. Then even Method C execute before MethodA finish completely

Answer (score 1):

> The receiver is not considered ready to execute until all of its
>   dependent operations have finished executing.
>   [Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html)

It seems that the dependencies, as stated by cfisher are backwards. Rather, these are the dependencies:

- Method C is dependent on Method B : means that B has to execute before C can start
- Method B is dependent on Method A : means that A has to execute before B can Start

Altogether, C cannot start until B executes, and since B cannot start until A executes, A has to execute first, then B, then C.

If you have interdependent pieces of code, another option would be to use blocks and execute the code asynchronously.

```
[self methodAWithCompletion:^{
    [self methodBWithCompletion:^{
        [self methodCWithCompletion:nil];
    }];

}];

//sample method A

- (void) methodAWithCompletion:(void(^)(void)completion {
    //your code

    if (completion) {
        completion();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to add dependencies to your NSOperations, im not too clued up on it, but its in the [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSOperation)